# draggingEntered not firing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdragginginfo

I have a subclass of NBox that I would like to drag around a canvas called dragBox.   I don't understand why draggingEntered isn't being fired on the following code.   I get a nice slideback image, but none of the destination delegates are getting fired.  Why?

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
  [[self superview] registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray     arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];


}
-(void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   [self dragImage:[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/bruce/Desktop/Untitled-1.png"] at:NSMakePoint(32, 32)  offset:NSMakeSize(0,0) event:theEvent pasteboard:[NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard] source:self slideBack:YES];




}
-(NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender // validate
{
NSLog(@"Updated");
return [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];

}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
NSLog(@"Drag Entered");

return [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];

}
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {

 NSLog(@"Move Box");
[self setFrameOrigin:[sender draggingLocation]];


    return YES;
}

-(BOOL) prepareForDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{NSLog(@"Prepared");
return YES;

}
```

Comment: NBox...  What is NBox?  XBox?  NSImageView?

Answer (score 0):

In your `mouseDown` method you are not putting anything in the pasteboard before you initiate the drag operation. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) for NSView states you need to add your data on the pasteboard before sending it to that message.

Whatever destination views you have are, or should be, registering for a certain drag type. If your pasteboard does not have any matching data for that type, the destinations will not fire any of the NSDraggingProtocol messages.

Comment: Hello,  I tried to set up an NSStringPboardType before invoking the call to dragImage.  It didn't work.  Still no events getting fired.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I was using the NSBox as both a destination and source.   The events weren't being fired when this was the case.   I moved registerDragTypes to the superview, the canvas, and implemented the draggingEntered and performDrag there.   It works now...

Bruce

Comment: I was going to comment on that, but I was assuming you were dragging one of your NSBox's instance onto other NSBox instances which would have worked. :/